# Displaying large amount of photos from the gallery in a gridview

Tags: android, android-gridview, picasso, android-adapterview

I have created a sample code to load all the images from the gallery and display them in a GridView.

I am using [picasso open source library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for displaying the images.

The `GridView` scroll is very slow, I have more than 1000 images that I want to display at once.

Here is my code for getting the images, which is a basic cursor.

```
paths = new ArrayList<String>();
cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        cursor.moveToPosition(i);
        paths.add(cursor.getString(1));
    }

}
```

And the following code is the `getview()` implementation in the `BaseAdpter` where I display the images.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SquaredImageView iv = (SquaredImageView) convertView;
    if (iv == null) {
        iv = new SquaredImageView(inflater.getContext());
    }
    String url = data.get(position);

    Picasso.with(inflater.getContext()).load(new File(url)).into(iv);
    return iv;
}



/** An image view which always remains square with respect to its width. */
final public class SquaredImageView extends ImageView {
    public SquaredImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquaredImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }
}
```

Comment: You must be doing something else on the UI thread that is not shown on the code you posted. The getView seems fine, and although I would use a `CursorAdapter` or at least fill the ArrayList using `cursorNext()`, there's no obvious reasons why the scroll should be slow. Are you executing that `query` in the UI thread or in a background thread? (also suggest to use CursorLoader)

Comment: @user1940676 Please I faced like your problem into my code,, I need to load more than 6000 pictures (which take a lot of time to load )  I do not know from where I can start to solve like such problem?! Does "Picasso library" solve such these problems?! also HOW your problem solved?! Thanks in advance !

Comment: @MaheeraJazi well I have a solution look up at the following link 
https://github.com/rexstjohn/UltimateAndroidCameraGuide/blob/master/camera/src/main/java/com/ultimate/camera/fragments/SimplePhotoGalleryListFragment.java
It might help you as well

Comment: Any chance you were able to fix this thing? I am having a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

You should just display the photos that are currently visible on the screen, as well as perhaps preloading the ones just above and below them. When they move off screen, you should get rid of them to clear memory.

Use `gridView.setOnScrollListener` to listen for scrolling. In the [onScroll()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html#onScroll(android.widget.AbsListView,%20int,%20int,%20int)) event, use the parameters `firstVisibleItem` and `visibleItemCount` to calculate which views to show and hide.

Comment: Picasso library already handles image loading, bitmap recycling and the necessary threading for that to happen. Certainly the issue is something else as he said that the "scroll is very slow".

Comment: toda, but it is not the issue I am having.